# Couldnt Find Id="your_question"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My error says that:

```
 Couldn't find Question with 'id'=your_questions" 
 and 
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in  QuestionsController#show
```

What should I do to fix it?

```
def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  @answer = Answer.new
end
```

on the second line it says where the error is.

Edit:

The Index View File

```
 <%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
<%= render 'common/form_errors', object: @question %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :body, "Question" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :body %>

    <%= f.submit "Ask a Question" %>
</p>
<% end %>


Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/" => "main_app#index"
  get "/location" => "location#location"
  post "/location/index" => "location#index"
  get "/location/index" => "location#index"
  get "/location/directions" => "location#directions"

  root to: 'questions#index'

  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :questions, except: [:new] do 
  resources :answers, only: [:create]
  end

  get '/register', to: 'users#new'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  get '/questions/:id', to: 'questions#your_questions'
  get '/search', to: 'questions#search'
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention you have this route:

```
get '/questions/your_questions', to: 'questions#your_questions
```

If you also have a route like following the restful style, you should also have something like:

```
get 'questions/:id', to: 'questions#your_questions'
```

Or a resource call. Anyway, so Rails is actually trying to access your show action passing "your_questions" as the id for the route. Write this route like this:

```
 get '/questions/:id', to: 'questions#show
```

This means: "If a request using the GET HTTP method follows the url 'questions/:id', then go to controller: questions and its action(method in the controller) called: your_questions" and pass into the params hash the value of id as in the URL.

Comment: so i replace the one i have now with the code you gave me?

Comment: it didnt work it messed up one of my other routes :(

Comment: That's why I needed to see your routes. Can't you edit the post with the content of the routes?

Comment: it wont let me because idk how to edit the code can i just email you please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58043/discussion-between-user00000001-and-tiago-farias).